# Parsing csv file into Boolean expression in Python

Tags: python, csv

I've got a csv file such as:

```
cutsets
x1
x3,x5
x2
x4,x6
x5,x7
x6,x8
x7,x9
x6,x8,x10
```

I run the following Py script:

```
import csv
# Reads Boolean expression from cutsets file
expr = []
with open("MCS_overlap.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # skip the first row
    next(csv_reader)
    for lines in csv_reader:
        expr = expr + lines + ['|']
    del expr[-1]
    final_expr=str(''.join(expr)).replace(",","&")
print("The Boolean expression is")
print(final_expr)
```

and get the output:

```
The Boolean expression is
x1|x3x5|x2|x4x6|x5x7|x6x8|x7x9|x6x8x10
```

With `final_expr=str(''.join(expr)).replace(",","&")` I was hoping to get a "&" between any two variables enclosed by a "|", e.g. "x4&x6","x6&x8&x10". But as can be seen the variables were simply concatenated. How do I accomplish insert "&" given I cannot change the format of the input file?

Thanks
Gui

Comment: Is there a reason why you are treating the data as CSV? It does not appear to be a "proper" (columnar) CSV – the commas do not separate values, instead the values *contain* commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
expr =[]
f = open('MCS_overlap.csv')
expr.append(f.read())
final_expr = expr[0].replace('\n', '|').replace(',', '&')
print(final_expr)
```

Prints:

```
'x1|x3&x5|x2|x4&x6|x5&x7|x6&x8|x7&x9|x6&x8&x10'
```

Comment: @GuiLarange As the question asker, you can accept one answer that solves your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @GuiLarange I see you have not accepted any answer so far. The link above by MisterMiyagi can help you understand how to do so.

Comment: OK, got it. My bad before

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `csv` module, `lines` is a list and as a result `expr` is a list with elements being all x-es and some pipes `|`. You can print to see for yourself. When you do `''.join(expr)` it just concatenates all elements, no commas (i.e. nothing to replace).

this should do

```
import csv
# Reads Boolean expression from cutsets file

with open("MCS_overlap.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # skip the first row
    next(csv_reader)
    lines = ('&'.join(line) for line in csv_reader)
    final_expr = '|'.join(lines)
print(final_expr)
```

of course, you can do without `csv` module

```
with open("MCS_overlap.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    next(csv_file)
    lines = (line.strip().replace(',', "&") for line in csv_file)
    final_expr = '|'.join(lines)
print(final_expr)
```

Note, both snippets not tested, but I expect to do the task for you.